# how to force matlab to display enough numbers on the plot X and Y?

Tags: matlab, plot, label

The problem is that matlab "cuts" some numbers and I do not recognize actual value. Look at the screenshot, on Y there are a lot of "0.0156" while I expect "0.01562" "0.01564" "0.01566" etc.

[image: screenshot]

How to say matlab to display enough numbers so I can recognize actual value?

Comment: look into the YTick and YTickLabel properties of axes

Comment: it would help if you post the data samples used to create the plot shown

Comment: @Amro sorry I lost this data. But I have something similar in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599065/creating-graph-from-text-file-where-axis-x-is-date-with-millisecond-precision-an

Comment: Here are some similar questions: [Matlab, how to adjust axis values on figures (scientific notaiton - not enough precision)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6495653/97160), [Suppress exponential formatting in figure ticks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3588293/97160)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to call:

```
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca,'YTick'))
```

Here is the before and after using the data from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599065/creating-graph-from-text-file-where-axis-x-is-date-with-millisecond-precision-an):

[image: before]
[image: after]

Created with:

```
y = [
    0.0155260005803643
    0.0155280030632315
    0.0155270018379389
    0.0155260006126463
    0.0155239981620611
    0.0155249993873537
];

plot(y)
```

Comment: it has been found that this not work accurate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683119/why-while-zooming-marker-changes-position/11684107#comment15494926_11684107

Comment: @javapowered: it does work, only with a side effect; it sets the [ticks mode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#zmw57dd0e32710) to `'manual'`, that means that if the axis limits change such as with zooming/panning (which is something you never mentioned in this question, so you can't fault me for that!), MATLAB will NOT automatically update the tick labels. The solution is do update the ticks yourself each time axis limits change (by listening for property-changed events, like it was pointed out in your other question).

Comment: @javapowered: the same fact I hinted at in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11678066/97160) of yours... I guess what I am trying to say is we can't account for all possible issues if you don't give us the context of your application in the question description.

Comment: ok, but this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687898/creating-graph-from-text-file-where-axis-x-is-date-with-millisecond-precision-an better solves my problem. adding link here so others can find it just in case :)

Answer (score 1):

I think `tick2text` by Kelly Kearney can do  it.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16003

Comment: why should I use some third-party functions? I expect matlab in core functionality to write such basic things as "axis numbers" correctly

Comment: @javapowered: that's actually a very useful function

Answer (score 1):

The set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca,'YTick')) works as suggested by Amro. Put it right after the plot command or the subplot command as I have done for some CFD work....

Sometimes pressure and velocity differentials can be very small and you need to plot at very small tickmarks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you give an example of "right after the (sub)plot command"?