# how to always display "labels" on axis X

Tags: matlab, plot, label, zooming

If I zoom several time graph all labels from axis X disapear (go away) and there are no visible axis X labels so it is not possible to understand the part of graph where am I.

How can I force matlab to always display labels on axis X and to update them automatically while zooming and to display enough digits so "neighboor" labels must be different.

Answer (score 1):

it depends, are you manually setting the tick marks yourself (`'XTick'` and `'XTickLabel'` axis properties)?

Try this simple example

```
plot(sin(1:10), 'o-')
```

without changing anything, you can zoom as much as you want, and the tick labels will always be visible

---

#### EDIT

The root cause of the problem is the same as the one raised in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11683119/97160), `datetick` function will manually set the tick labels, thus disabling automatic update on zoom/pan.

The good news is there are already [submissions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15029-datetickzoom-automatically-update-dateticks) on [FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20422-datetick-with-zooming-panning-and-subplots) that tries to solve this exact problem with DATETICK

Comment: i'm using that: `datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS');` if i disable that line labels become visible, but I want to see "time"

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem even on the new version of MATLAB (r2014). MATLAB does not display sufficient x-axis tick labels as you zoom-in. After several experiments I found the following workaround. Following is a plot before implementing the solution. MATLAB displays only three XTick labels on the x-axis even though there is sufficient space for more (there are often even less labels as you zoom in more).
[image: After zooming-in ML displays only three XTick labels on the x-axis even though there is sufficient space for more.]

Suspecting that MATLAB thinks that it does not have sufficient space to display more labels, a workaround can be to rotate the labels. To do that, after you issue the plot commands, e.g.

```
plot(tsX);
hold on;
plot(tsY);
plot(tsZ);
```

add the following command

```
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',90);
```

Now MATLAB plots with more labels
[image: After rotating the X Tick labels MATLAB plots more labels as you zoom-in.]

I am going to report this as a bug to the MATLAB guys.