# why while zooming marker changes position?

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming

I plot graph and markers on it. However I see strange behavior - marker changes it's position while zooming. I've created [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1zc6jRqh0g&feature=youtu.be) about that (please switch to fullhd while watching to be able to see numbers)

my code:

```
clear

fDevide = fopen('devideHistory.log');
data = textscan(fDevide, '%f:%f:%f:%f %f,%f %f,%f');
fclose(fDevide);

% hh:min:sec:millisec
secvec = [60*60 60 1 1e-3];
x = [data{1:4}] * secvec';

flvec = [1 1e-16];
y = [data{5:6}] * flvec';

xindays = x / (24*60*60);

plot(xindays, y);
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca,'YTick'))
datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS');

hold on

fDeals = fopen('deals.log');
data = textscan(fDeals, '%f:%f:%f:%f %f,%f %f,%f %f,%f %f');
fclose(fDeals);

% hh:min:sec:millisec
secvec = [60*60 60 1 1e-3];
x = [data{1:4}] * secvec';

flvec = [1 1e-16];
y = [data{5:6}] * flvec';

xindays = x / (24*60*60);

plot(xindays, y, 'go','MarkerSize',6,'LineWidth',3);
```

source files: [devideHistory.log](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49126809/matlab/devideHistory.log) [deals.log](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49126809/matlab/deals.log)

The question is why marker changes it's position. I expect it to be always at the same position (from file deals.log)

Comment: I don't see the problem. Are you talking about the green dots? They are plotted as datapoints, so of they are related to the axis, and not the frame. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Bernhard yes i'm talking about green dots. i expect each green dot to be at exact position. for example `10:02:00:072 0,0196422427423108` where time is X and value is Y. but they are moving while zooming! sometimes they at `0,01964` sometimes at `0,01963` sometimes at `0,01962` and sometimes at `0,01961`. the same dot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you set the y-axis labels

```
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca,'YTick'))
```

when you now start zooming, the ticks themselves change, but the labels don't.
You notice this by zooming in and at the same time observing that the range of the y-axis does not change.

I think what you intended to do with the above yticklabel overruling is increase the accuracy of those ytick labels. But you forget to keep those labels up to date with the actual values.

This guy: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-axes-tick-labels-format/ has spent some time of making this an automatic process using callbacks.

On the file exchange the same person has a script to all automate it for you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36254-ticklabelformat

so you only have to call

```
ticklabelformat(gca,'y','%.6g')
```

or any other format you want

Comment: omg.. i just wonder how hard to do so basic things in so proffesional program as matlab which designed exactly for doing such stuff. why matlab doesn't display labels on axis correctly and in friendly maner, why I should do some hacks which introduce new bugs...

Comment: @javapowered actually, you misused the yticklabels, normally they are used for putting words there, like `'high','medium','low'` for example. How is matlab supposed to know that the labels you'd set are linked to the real tick values... The only thing you can blame matlab, is that there is no option to change the default precision of ticks shown; hence the link I gave you to fix another way

Comment: `The only thing you can blame matlab, is that there is no option to change the default precision of ticks shown`. Well this is a big problem IMHO. Also I have to use `datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS');` after that I loose x labels as well.

Comment: have you even read the link (http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-axes-tick-labels-format/) I provided: a simple solution to fix it yourself. And there is always the feature request (explained [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2008/01/14/making-a-feature-request/) )

Comment: Ok i'm reading it. it just doens't look as simple as my problem sounds :) But if it may help. I will read/try it in 2-3 hours.

Comment: Ok I want to try to use this script. I've downloaded it. How to install it? Should i just put it to the folder with my script? Sorry i'm absolutely novice in matlab.

Comment: yes, put in a folder where matlab will find it (your current working folder will do fine), plot your data and then run `ticklabelformat(gca,'y','%g')`