# creating graph from text file where axis X is date with millisecond precision and Y is value with markers

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, zooming

I still can not create something usable in matlab.

The task is pretty simple. I have two files: [devideHistory.log](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49126809/matlab/devideHistory.log) [deals.log](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49126809/matlab/deals.log) In both files lets consider only first two column. So first file contains X and Y which should form graphic. Second file contains X and Y of markers that should be displayed on the graphic. With help of this community such program was created

```
clear

fDevide = fopen('devideHistory.log');
data = textscan(fDevide, '%f:%f:%f:%f %f,%f %f,%f');
fclose(fDevide);

% hh:min:sec:millisec
secvec = [60*60 60 1 1e-3];
x = [data{1:4}] * secvec';

flvec = [1 1e-16];
y = [data{5:6}] * flvec';

xindays = x / (24*60*60);

plot(xindays, y);
% set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca,'YTick'))
% datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS');

hold on

fDeals = fopen('deals.log');
data = textscan(fDeals, '%f:%f:%f:%f %f,%f %f,%f %f,%f %f');
fclose(fDeals);

% hh:min:sec:millisec
secvec = [60*60 60 1 1e-3];
x = [data{1:4}] * secvec';

flvec = [1 1e-16];
y = [data{5:6}] * flvec';

xindays = x / (24*60*60);

plot(xindays, y, 'go','MarkerSize',6,'LineWidth',3);

% i need to set enough precision on Y but this doesn't work because
% while zooming labels doesn't update
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca,'YTick')) 

% i want to have "time" on X but this doesn't work because
% while zooming new labels doesn't appear
datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS');
```

Result:
[image: graphic]

But I have two problems with zooming feature:

- while zooming in labels from X disappear and as a result there are not labels at X at all [how to always display "labels" on axis X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677601/how-to-always-display-labels-on-axis-x)
- while zooming labels on Y is not updated as a result markers are displayed on the wrong position [why while zooming marker changes position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683119/why-while-zooming-marker-changes-position)

Well my task is pretty simple and straightforward. Are there simple and straightforward solution in matlab for it? Code above already contains several "hacks" and still doesn't work as expected. I'm afraid contining hacking it doesn't make sense. Could someone suggest another approach? Probably matlab just not suitable for my needs?

Comment: your markers are displayed correctly, the labels are wrong, get your facts straight! You have an updating problem for customized labeling; fix that with callbacks or even simpler with [ticklabelformat](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36254-ticklabelformat) which does it all for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36254-ticklabelformat
2. Remove your own tick labeling calls, these ones:

   ```
   set(gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca,'YTick')) 
   datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS');
   ```
3. Replace them with

   ```
   ticklabelformat(gca,'y','%g')
   ticklabelformat(gca,'x',{@tick2datestr,'x','HH:MM:SS'})
   ```
4. Make a new helper function `tick2datestr.m` containing:

   ```
   function tick2datestr(hProp,eventData,axName,dateformat)    %#ok<INUSL>
       hAxes = eventData.AffectedObject;
       tickValues = get(hAxes,[axName 'Tick']);
       tickLabels = arrayfun(@(x)datestr(x,dateformat),tickValues,'UniformOutput',false);
       set(hAxes,[axName 'TickLabel'],tickLabels);
   end
   ```

most of this helper function is btw copied straight out of ticklabelformat.

Yes, you can consider this as hacking, but as long as TheMathworks doesn't implement your desired 'straightforward' solution, you have to create your own functionality.

Comment: where should I place downloaded file? how to link it with my script?

Comment: i've tried to download this file several times but still can not receive "full" version. file is cut. file contains only 106 lines and the last line is "set(hAxes,[axName 'TickLabel'],tickLabels)". i will try to google it on another hosting right away probably something wrong with mathworks

Comment: here it's visible in plain text: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36254-ticklabelformat-set-a-dynamic-format-of-axes-tick-labels/content/ticklabelformat.m

Comment: thanks, then I downloaded full version of it, I was not expecting that if finished without "end" or something like that :) so the only question is where should I place it. i will try to place it in the same folder as my script.